# How to default the media browser to tree view

Tags: configuration, media-library

This is a really minor issue. But is it possible to have the "Select Media" browser **default to the tree view** as opposed to list view? I imagine there would be a config setting somewhere. I just feel it would create better interaction and would also be one less click for most of our users.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Sitecore 7.1-7.5 there is a configuration file called Sitecore.Speak.config in the include folder. In that file find the following line:

```xml
<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" 
       with="/sitecore/client/Sitecore/Common/Dialogs/SelectMediaDialog" />
```

And replace it with this

```xml
<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" 
        with="/sitecore/client/Sitecore/Common/Dialogs/SelectMediaViaTreeDialog" />
```

In Sitecore 8+, this particular configuration has been moved to a file called Sitecore.Speak.Applications.config

For more information see http://ggullentops.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/configure-media-browser-default-view.html

Comment: You beat me to it with my own blog! Cool ;)  If it works on v8, I'll update my blog with the info on the new location.

Comment: don't forget to patch it :)

Comment: Updated the blog with v8 info and patch..

Comment: can this be done per field? I have a template with a specific image field where I want to disable the Search altogether, but only there

Comment: Note that for Sitecore 8+, the path to the TreeDialog version is slightly different: `/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaViaTreeDialog`